# How to make loops multithread in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

How can I make these loops parallel with multithreading capability of ruby?

1.

```
from = 'a' * 1
to = 'z' * 3


("#{from}".."#{to}").each do |combination|  

    # ...

end
```

2.

```
@@alphabetSet_tr.length.times do |i|
    @@alphabetSet_tr.length.times do |j|
        @@alphabetSet_tr.length.times do |k|
            combination = @@alphabetSet_tr[i] + @@alphabetSet_tr[j] + @@alphabetSet_tr[k]
        end
    end
end
```

Note: @@alphabetSet_tr is an array which has 29 items

Comment: Just put the command inside `Thread.new{...}`, and then `join` them somewhere.

Comment: You could use `peach` gem, or one of other parallel each implementations. I don't suggest nested loops though - use `Array#combination`, `Array#product`, `Array#zip`... to construct a single list. Note that parallelism through threads is kind of useless on MRI for speedups, use JRuby or Rubinius for that.

Comment: What do you mean by parallel? What is your need? I'm not sure this is needed for performance - you do a simple calculation 25K times...

Comment: @sawa this is not useful in this situation. Because, the loops are serial. I'm trying to divide loops' iterations into separate cores of single CPU.

Comment: @UriAgassi Agassi the codes are just an example. Normally, I am dealing with 50-GB combinations. Think about it. I need parallelism. With word parallel, I referred to divide for loop iterations into separate cores of single CPU.

Comment: As I said, threads in MRI do not actually execute in parallel. You can use MRI threads to avoid blocking in IO, for example, but not to actually speed up processing, since MRI cannot execute more than one Ruby thing at a time due to [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock). You need either Rubinius or JRuby which do not have GIL, or you need to `fork` and use processes instead of threads. [parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) is a nice gem that allows you to use both processes or threads to parallelise your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to utilize your cores, you can use a [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) to divide the workload between a constant number of threads:

```
require 'thread'

queue = Queue.new

number_of_cores = 32

threads = (0..number_of_cores).map do
  Thread.new do
    combination = queue.pop
    while combination
      # do stuff with combination...

      # take the next combination from the queue
      combination = queue.pop
    end
  end
end

# fill the queue:
("#{from}".."#{to}").each do |combination|  
  queue << combination
end

# drain the threads
number_of_cores.times { queue << nil }

threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

If you fear that the size of the queue itself would be an issue - you can use [`SizedQueue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/SizedQueue.html) which will block push operations if it gets larger than a certain size - capping its memory usage -

```
queue = SizedQueue.new(10000)
```

Comment: Thnx for your contribute. It is seminal, but there is problem due to usage of Queue in "#fill the queue" part of your code. Variable queue takes all combinations in that part. This means queue needs RAM memory. Whereas, I'm dealing with 50, 60 maybe 100-GB combinations. Queue cannot carry this load due to memory capacity.

Answer (score 1):

```
from = 'a' * 1
to = 'z' * 3


threads = ("#{from}".."#{to}").map do |combination|  
  Thread.new do
      # ...
  end
end

# In case you want the main thread waits all the child threads.
threads.each(&:join)
```